# Retrieving data from the preceding rows w/ Hlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

first time posting so Im hoping for some assistance.

I have a table of data, and the primary key for the Hlookup is sitting of the 3 row down. I need a Hlookup to retrieve the data above.

For example...

Row 1 Science

Row 2 Period 1

Row 3 Eric

The data cannot be changed due to the nature of the spreadsheet. But I need to build a timetable based on particular names and the information associated to that person.

So Eric is teaching Science in Period 1. That needs to be added to a seperate sheet.
Outcome

Eric

Science

Period 1

A Hlookup would be perfect if it were possible to retrieve the preceding rows.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance!

[IMAGE GOOGLE SHEETS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mvsw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index()/Match()` combination may work for you. Try below-

<kbd>E3</kbd> cell formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)-2)`

<kbd>E4</kbd> cell formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)-1)`

[image]

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your reply. Thats exactly on the right path to what I am needing.

Is there a way to then have this search across a horizontal range?

Comment: @Marcus I think possible. You can share a sample google-sheet with dummy data and showing expected output. Then we may suggest better formula for you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WM49OpkZtAshFZCTJEa8YfB4Am4ounla05y8Hz1Kpv8/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a dummy sheet...

Comment: Try `=INDEX($A$3:$C$4,1,MATCH($E$2,$A$5:$C$5,0))` and `=INDEX($A$3:$C$4,2,MATCH($E$2,$A$5:$C$5,0))`